# Artinian ideal and regular sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

I want to show that given a homogeneous ideal $I$ of a polynomial ring

$R=k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$, $I$ contains a regular sequence of length $n$ if and only if $I$ is Artinian.